# jQuery - API options as a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

I am playing with [Instafeed](http://instafeedjs.com/) plugin and there is shown an option as a function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'awesome',
        clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
    });
    feed.run();
</script>
```

> before (function) - A callback function called before fetching images
>   from Instagram.

How can I set up this option?
I've tried

```
before: 'Loading...',
```

But obviously nothing has happened.

How can I set up parameter as a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions in javascript are just a special class of objects.  You can assign them like any other object:

```
var beforeFunc = function(){...};

...

before: beforeFunc,
```

or defined inline

```
before: function(){....},
```

Make sure you're passing a function object and not the result of the function.  This will not work correctly

```
before: beforeFunc(),
```

because it will run the function and set `before` to the return value

#### Update

So if you want to show a message, you can define a message area somewhere on your page like this

```
<div id="messageArea"></div>
```

and then have your beforeFunc set like this

```
var beforeFunc = function(){
    $("#messageArea").html("loading...");
}
```

and then you can clear it when its completed

```
var afterFunc = function(){
    $("#messageArea").html("");
}

...


before:beforeFunc,
after: afterFunc,
```

Comment: thank you Ben for the answer, but I still cannot figure out how to put there a message than will be the photos loaded.

Answer (score 1):

```
before: function() {
 /* function code to execute here */
}
```